# Extracting the name of the root node in XML using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

From the below table,

[image]

Is there a way to extract the name of the Root node 'Main' alone from the column 'XML_data' using SQL server?

UPDATE:

```
DECLARE @ProdID int 

create table #xmldata(id int,data xml)
insert into #xmldata
select
id = '011', 
data =  '<Root>  
<ProductDescription ProductID="1" ProductName="Road Bike">  
<Features>  
  <Warranty>1 year parts and labor</Warranty>  
  <Maintenance>3 year parts and labor extended maintenance is available</Maintenance>  
</Features>  
</ProductDescription>  
</Root>' 

select * from #xmldata

SET @ProdID =  #xmldata.data.value('(/Root)[1]', 'varchar' )  
SELECT @ProdID  

drop table #xmldata
```

Comment: Can you share the code you wrote after you read the SQL Server XML docs that did not produce the desired output?

Comment: Added the code here. But pls read my question again. I don't know how to extract the data at all which means I need support to write for data extraction.

Comment: I updated your temp table definition to make `[data]` an XML column so that you can use XML functions on the column.  They don't work on VARCHAR columns.  Also, your script does not align with what is in the table in the screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Is there a way to extract the name of the **Root node 'Main'** alone from the column 'XML_data' using SQL server?*

Yes, it is possible:

```
SELECT s.c.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') AS root_name, sub.*
FROM #xmldata sub
CROSS APPLY sub.data.nodes('/*') s(c);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7ee5a502ca91779efe54c0497edd6328)**

---

## EDIT:

Or using `.query()` method:

```
SELECT sub.data.query('local-name(/*[1])') AS root_name, sub.*
FROM #xmldata sub;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c98c3f75f2ddf99140a9c5f3ba93605b)**

---

## EDIT 2:

As mentioned by [@Shnugo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5089204/shnugo) you could use `.value()` method without `.nodes()`:

```
SELECT sub.data.value('local-name((/*)[1])','varchar(100)') AS root_name, sub.*
FROM #xmldata sub;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo3](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=da8369fdcea8137dd62734d0830acfdd)**

Comment: The easiest is without `nodes()` or `.query()`. Just `sub.data.value('local-name((/*)[1])','varchar(100)')`

Comment: @Shnugo **** Thanks, I like this version.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a (correct) script to create the table in your screenshot.  The query shows how to select the value of the `name` node from each row:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #xmldata;
CREATE TABLE #xmldata
(
    cid INT,
    cidtype CHAR,
    xml_data XML
);

INSERT #xmldata SELECT 1001,'N','<Main><ID>1001</ID><details><name>John</name><age>12</age></details></Main>';
INSERT #xmldata SELECT 1001,'N','<Main><ID>1003</ID><details><name>Diane</name><age>25</age></details></Main>';
INSERT #xmldata SELECT 1001,'N','<Main><ID>1004</ID><details><name>Kippy</name><age>26</age></details></Main>';

SELECT xml_data.value('(/Main/details/name)[1]','varchar(100)') AS [name]
FROM #xmldata;
```

Comment: May I ask how does it solve OP's question(that is getting  **root element name**)?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I interpreted that as "get the value of the name node".  Since all of the records in the sample data have the same root node name that seemed to make the most logical sense.

Comment: I wouldn't say so based on `"Is there a way to extract the name of the Root node 'Main' alone from the column 'XML_data' using SQL server?"`. But it may be a bit vague.

Comment: Yeah, seems you interpreted it more correctly than I did.  Vague indeed.